# Change font size in longtable

Tags: fonts, longtable, fontsize

I am using a `longtable` in LaTeX, given the many variables included in my analysis. However, my table is over 2 pages and I would like to change the font size, in order to fit it into one page.

Here's the code:

```latex
\documentclass [7pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document} 

\footnotesize\begin{longtable}{rcccccc}
\hline\hline
                    \toprule
\hline\hline
                      &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}\\
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{OLS}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{2SLS}\\
\hline
Rich20\%/Poor20\% Origin &      -58.97\sym{***}&      -314.9\sym{***} \\
                    &     (12.333)         &     (108.494)         \\

Rich20\%/Poor20\% Destination &      -49.35\sym{***}&       61.34         \\
                    &     (12.466)         &      (37.978)         \\

Distance            &      -312.2\sym{*}         &      -2.153\sym{***}\\
                    &     (172.572)         &    (0.168)         \\

Distance^2            &       0.286\sym{*}         &     0.001\sym{***}\\
                    &      (3.875)         &     (0.000)         \\

Unemployment Origin &       12.20\sym{***} &       32.38\sym{*}         \\
                    &      (3.874)         &      (18.027)         \\

Lagged Unemployment Origin&      -20.30\sym{***}&      -48.67\sym{***} \\
                    &     (3.991)         &     (17.817)         \\

Unemployment Destination&      -1.980         &       4.541         \\
                    &     (2.830)         &      (17.077)         \\

Lagged Unemployment Destination&       3.180         &      -5.618         \\
                    &      (2.980)         &     (17.512)         \\

Population Origin         &   -0.000\sym{***} &  0.000         \\
                    &     (0.001)         &      (0.000)         \\

Lagged Population Origin        &   -0.000\sym{***}&    0.000         \\
                    &     (0.001)         &      (0.000)         \\

Population Destination     &   -0.000\sym{**}  &    0.000         \\
                    &     (0.000)         &      (0.000)         \\

Lagged Population Destination   &   -0.000\sym{***}&  -0.000         \\
                    &     (0.000)         &     (0.000)         \\

GDP Origin          &    -0.003         &      0.049         \\
                    &     (0.008)         &      (0.038)         \\

Lagged GDP Origin        &    -0.008         &     -0.037         \\
                    &     (0.008)         &     (0.037)         \\

GDP Destination     &     -0.020\sym{***} &     -0.051         \\
                    &     (0.006)         &     (0.035)         \\

Lagged GDP Destination   &      0.028\sym{***}&      0.065\sym{*}         \\
                    &      (0.006)         &      (0.035)         \\

Education Origin    &    -51307.1\sym{***}&    -31400.9         \\
                    &     (13329.44)         &     (60334.39)         \\

Lagged Education Origin  &     14001.5         &     34231.7         \\
                    &      (12278.91)         &      (59090.07)         \\

Education Destination&      7550.5         &     39697.6         \\
                    &      (10855.85)         &      (57873.18)         \\

Lagged Education Destination&      5114.8         &     33573.5         \\
                    &      (9168.611)         &      (57415.35)         \\

Crime Origin        &       1.850         &       10.76\sym{**}  \\
                    &      (1.249)         &      (4.940)         \\

Lagged Crime Origin      &       2.486\sym{***} &       14.65\sym{***} \\
                    &      (0.757)         &      (4.559)         \\

Crime Destination          &      -1.261         &      -4.797         \\
                    &     (0.922)         &     (4.969)         \\

Lagged Crime Destination         &       1.397         &      -4.829         \\
                    &      (1.133)         &     (4.577)         \\

Constant            &     53738.2\sym{*}         &      -802.6\sym{***}\\
                    &      (28311.1)         &     (238.207)         \\
Region fixed effects & Yes & Yes \\
Period fixed effects & Yes & Yes \\
\textit{R}-squared & .232 & .722 \\ 
Observations        &        2660         &        2660         \\
Number of regions & 20 & 20\\

Underidentification test & No & 359.227 \\
Chi-sq(2) P-val & No & 0.000\\
Weak identification test & No & 205.627 \\
Sargan statistic & No & 0.303\\
Chi-sq(1) P-val & No & 0.5822\\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{Standard Errors} in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.1\), \sym{**} \(p<0.05\), \sym{***} \(p<0.01\)}\\
\caption{Effect of Rich20\%/Poor20\% on Internal Mobility.\label{tab1}}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the reason to use `longtable` in the first place if you want the contents to stay on one page? You can put a `\begingroup\small` before `\begin{longtable}` and an `\endgroup` after `\end{longtable}` (as you already do with `\footnotesize` but without limiting its scope to the `longtable`).

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Remember your table must remain readable. The `extarticle` class, from `extsizes` provides document sizes  from 8 pt to 20pt.

Comment: Also your MWE lacks a definition of `\sym` and uses `^` outside of math mode.

Comment: You can select arbitrary fontsizes using `\fontsize{<height>}{<baseline skip>}\selectfont`.

Comment: Your table is very huge ... I wouldn't try to squeeze it on one page since the font will become so small that it will be very difficult to read. If you not care for this, add `{\tiny` before your `longtable` and `}` after it. Is this what you looking for?

Comment: `7pt` is not a valid option for the `article` class. Please also explain why you declare 7 columns but only use 3 of them.

Comment: Would it be ok to put the standard error in the same row as the actual value? Like this you might save a lot of space since your table is quite narrow but much too long for a sigle page. The output could look like the following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zSdI.png